# Rotate image using image holder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have created one app that allow to rotate image and crop image. When my first app start with original image, it is fine with crop image. But the problem is that when I rotate it once, my crop tools cannot get top,left,width,height of the image as the original one. My code as below .Can anyone help me with this problem?
My code:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#crop").click(function(e){
        var Imgwidth = $('#face').width(), 
            Imgheight =  $('#face').height(),
            faceOffset = $('#face').offset(),
            imgOffset = $('#imgHolder').find('img').offset(), 
            imgX1 = faceOffset.left-imgOffset.left,
            imgY1 = faceOffset.top-imgOffset.top,
            imgX2 =imgX1+Imgwidth,
            imgY2 = imgY1+Imgheight;
        var imgNval = new Array();

          var imageSrc ='Penguins.jpg';    
          var imageObj=new Image();
          imageObj.src=imageSrc; 
        selx1 = imgX1;
        sely1 = imgY1;
        selx2 = imgX2;
        sely2 = imgY2;
        selw = Imgwidth;
        selh = Imgheight;
        console.log(imgX1);
        console.log(imgY1);
        /*console.log(imgX2);
        console.log(imgY2);*/

        /*Passing from one page to another page*/
        var canvas=document.getElementById("Mystore1");
        var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.canvas.height = Imgheight;
        context.canvas.width=Imgwidth;
        context.drawImage(imageObj, imgX1, imgY1, selw, selh, 3, 3, Imgwidth,     canvas.height-5);
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        var loop=0; 
         $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("#left").click(function(){
                loop+=90;
                  $("#imageHolder").rotate({ animateTo:loop });
                });
             });
         $(document).ready(function(e) {
             $("#right").click(function(){
                 loop-=90;
                $("#imageHolder").rotate({animateTo:loop});
            });
         });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $(".frame").draggable();
                        });
    </script>
  <canvas id="Mystore1">Your Browser Doesn't support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>
  <div id="imgHolder">
    <img src="Penguins.jpg" id="image"/> 
  </div>
  <div class="frame"><img src="face.jpg" width="80" height="80" id="face"     class="frames"/></div>
  <button id="crop">Crop Me</button>
  <button id="left">Left</button>
  <button id="right">Right</button>
</body>
</html>
```